# Search and replace in Mongo commandline

Tags: linux, mongodb

I can find all the `first_name` values by

```
> db.users.find().forEach( function(myDoc) { print( "first_name: " + myDoc.first_name ); } );
first_name: test1
first_name: test2
first_name: test3
first_name: test4
>
```

but when I try and change them all to `testing`, then I get

```
> db.users.find().forEach( function(myDoc) { $set: {myDoc.first_name: "testing"};  } );
2018-06-27T16:58:54.268+0200 E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
>
```

**Question**

Can anyone see why it doesn't replace all the `first_name` values to `testing`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) can be used only inside `update` statements since it is a field update operator. So your code can be changed to:

```
db.users.find().forEach( function(myDoc) { db.users.update({_id: myDoc._id}, { $set: { first_name: "testing"} } ) ;  } );
```

Which can be achieved without fetching all documents:

```
db.users.update({}, { $set: { first_name: "testing3"} }, { multi: true } )
```

or if you want to modify document inside `forEach` then you can use `.save()` method in Mongo shell like:

```
db.users.find().forEach( function(myDoc) { myDoc.first_name = "testing2"; db.users.save(myDoc); } );
```